# jQuery methods, variable scope in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, scope

I've got a code like that:

```
function some_func_validate(some_id) {
    var variable_to_return = false; // i wanna use that
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/something/'+some_id+'/check',
        success: function(response){
            variable_to_return = true; // in this place
        }
    });
    return variable_to_return;
}
```

So, code'll return false value. How i can assign a value to a variable without using DOM of HTML document, such as assign a value to an html attribute of some tag and then get that via jQuery ???

How to use any 'global' variables in JavaScript?

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function. Move any code that relies upon `variable_to_return` into the success callback.

Comment: `$.ajax` is async. Please make your own research

Answer (score 1):

Since ajax is asynchronous, you need to do something like this

```
function some_func_validate(some_id, cb) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/something/'+some_id+'/check',
        success: function(response){
            cb(response);
        }
    });

}
```

And call it using

```
some_func_validate(some_id, function(response){
    //handle response here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this while doing the asynchronous call. You can force synchronous call, but this will result in the freezing you page before the server return response. Add async: flase switch  to your call.

```
function some_func_validate(some_id) {
   var variable_to_return = false; // i wanna use that
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       async: false,
       url: '/something/'+some_id+'/check',
       success: function(response){
           variable_to_return = true; // in this place
       }
   });
   return variable_to_return;
}
```

But I would still recommend refactoring your code and using the variable in the callback only.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has, since version 1.5, utilities to handle management of callbacks and asynchronous invocations using objects called [Deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Using these types of objects, it is easier for a client to add callbacks to be called when some background work has been completed. Here is an example using your code:

```
function some_func_validate(some_id) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        context = {
           id: some_id,
           success: false
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/something/'+some_id+'/check'
    })
    .done(function(response){
       context.success = true;
       context.content = response;
       deferred.resolveWith(context);
    })
    .fail(function() {
       deferred.rejectWith(context)
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Example usage:

```
some_func_validate(5).then (
    function (context) {
      // Handle successful validation.
      console.log(context);
    },
    function (context) {
      // Handle failed validation.
      console.log(context)
    }
);
```

Another usage example:

```
function logger (context) {
   console.log(context);
}

function onSuccessfulValidation (context) {
   // Handle successful validation.
   // context contains {id, content, success}
}

function onFailedValidation (context) {
   // Handle failed validation.
   // context contains {id, success}
}

some_func_validate(3).then (
    [logger, onSuccessfulValidation],
    [logger, onFailedValidation]
);
```